# How come Eccentricity and Polar angle are orthogonal dimensions?

Tags: polar-coordinates, orthogonality

I am trying to understand the process of creating Visual Field Maps (VFM, also knows and Retinotopy) using fMRI with respect to the two orthogonal dimensions in visual space: **eccentricity** and **polar angle**. I am reading a chapter of an open access book called [Visual Field Map Organization in Human Visual Cortex](https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/39300).

As per my understanding, eccentricity represents how circular a curve is. Higher the circularity, lower would be the eccentricity. And, polar angle represents the angle of a point w.r.t the x-axis in case of Polar coordinate system.

[Image Source](https://planetplanet.net/2014/10/06/real-life-sci-fi-worlds-1-the-eccentric-earth/)

[image]

[Image Source](https://plus.maths.org/content/maths-minute-polar-coordinates)

[image]

**Question:** Taking the above facts into consideration, why has it been said in [the book](https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/39300) that the Eccentricity and Polar Angles are two orthogonal dimensions?

Comment: I am not sure that eccentricity in these VFM is the same eccentricity that we use for conic sections. Please look up in the literature what is the definition that they use

Comment: Likely you should read *orthogonal* as *independent*, i.e. knowledge of one of these quantities has no bearing on the other.

Comment: @Andrei: Reading some more material, I have a feeling that in the context of VFM, by eccentricity they simply means radius.

Comment: Yes, in an $(r,\theta)$ polar grid for any point, the radial line $r=r_1$ is a circle with eccentricity $=r_1=e$ ..that is always perpendicular i.e., orthogonal to the radial line $ r=r_1.$  There is no ellipse ovality context here.